# Is it possible to update an instance in an ontology (.pprj extension) with JESS in Java?

Tags: java, semantic-web, ontology, protege, jess

My ontology was done with `Protégé` and has been saved as a `Protégé project (.pprj)`.

I am developing a Java application that should update an instance,which is a date.

Can you tell me how I proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: Ok, it was a stupid question I guess? ^^' I am a beginner in JESS and I didn't search very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(In case someone needs an answer)

It is totally possible to update the facts .pprj with`JESS`(using `JessTab`). The function is **slot-set**. It goes like:

`(slot-set X Y Z)`

With`X`being the name of the instance (In a class Person, it can be Maria for example),`Y`the slot you want to update (age for example) and`Z`the new value that you want to affect the`Y`slot ("21" for example).